# Disable SSH Password Warning

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh

How I can disable the SSH warning after a restart? I tried to remove the etc/profile.d/sshpwd.sh file and some other methods but they don't work.

I have a Pi 3, using Raspbian Stretch with the latest upgrade as of Dec/22/018.

Comment: @goldilocks Looks like this is the RPF Raspbian specific ssh password nag message. Answer is at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1406914#p1407065 (Looks like same OP to me)

Comment: @Dirk thanks for pointing that out. If it really is specific to Raspbian it could be reopened here. My question to Rich would therefore be, is there anything left unaswered on that thread over at rpi.org?

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to disable it is to simply read the instructions and change to userid=pi password from "raspberry" to **any other string**".